# Handle Fragment Backstack According to the Current Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

**Problem 1**

I have a Navigation Drawer and most of my fragment transactions happens from here.
So say I have 4 Items in my drawer and I am doing the transaction from all of them. So if I am at the fragment `[A]` and now I click on the fragment `[B]`, I need to come back to the previous fragment i.e. `[A]`. But if I keep clicking on the `Item B` of the navigation drawer that opens the fragment `[B]`, I keep adding it to the backstack and when I press the back button, I am still at the same fragment.

**Problem 2**

How do I achieve the `Clear Top` behavior that is used for the intents for the fragments. As intents have the power to clear the activities from the stack from the top only, I want to achieve the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

***Problem 1 & 2 solution Idea:***

Create an Interface say `FragmentInstanceHandler`

```
public interface FragmentInstanceHandler {
   public void openFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag);
}
```

Create a `BaseFragment` like below and extend this to all your `Fragment` classes:

```
public BaseFragment extends Fragment {
   public FragmentInstanceHandler fragmentInstanceHandler;
   public void setFragmentInstanceHandler(FragmentInstanceHandler fragmentInstanceHandler) {
       this.fragmentInstanceHandler = fragmentInstanceHandler;
   }
}
```

Implement the `FragmentInstanceHandler` interface to the `Activity` in which you are going to open all the Fragments. Let's say `Activity` is `MainActivity`:

```
public MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentInstanceHandler {
  private BaseFragment currentFragment;
  @Override
  public void openFragment(BaseFragment fragment, String fragmentTag) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment oldFragmentInstance = fragmentManager .findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate (fragmentTag, 0);
   if (!fragmentPopped && oldFragmentInstance == null) {
        fragment.setFragmentInstanceHandler(this);       
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentTag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        currentFragment = fragment;
    } else if(fragmentPopped ){
        currentFragment = oldFragmentInstance;
     }
     if(mDrawerLayout!= null)
           mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
 }

}
```

Now whenever you want to open a new `Fragment` even from any other `Fragment` you can call method like below, It is advised to provide new **tag** if you want to have new instance of same `Fragment`:

```
fragmentInstanceHandler.openFragment(new MyFragment(), "FragmentNewInstance");
```

You can tweak `FragmentInstanceHandler`to add your own method to replace the current `Fragment` instead of adding. Above solution just gives you an idea how you can acheive your solution by putting and mananging all your code from one place.